# Getting p12 certificates already installed in system with Qt

Tags: ssl, qnetworkaccessmanager

I made some research in Google and was unable to find the way to get CA certificates already installed in system

My problem is that my application should pass authentication through swissID authentication system.
SwissID provides with USB key which stores certificates. When user inserts USB to soscket windows/MAC automatically installs p12 certificates to system.
My problem is that I can't find way to get this certificates from OS and pass them to NetworkAccessManager.

Programming language is: C++
Framework: Qt4.7
OS: Windows/MacOS/Linux

Any help is appreciate.

Thanks
Best Regards
Taron Sargsyan

Comment: What OS, language are you asking about? Please update your question with this additional information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I was looking for was
QList QSslConfiguration::caCertificates ();
From Qt4 documentation.

> > Returns this connection's CA certificate database. The CA certificate database is used by the socket during the handshake phase to validate the peer's certificate. It can be moodified prior to the handshake with addCaCertificate(), addCaCertificates(), and setCaCertificates().